# WPF: DataTemplate and UserControl map not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm starting a WPF project. Trying to binding usercontrol by viewmodel. Where viewmodel define with dataType at DataTemplate in Application.Reousrces. But user control not bind. Any one can help me?

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MatterPanelViewModel}">
            <uc:MatterPanel />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Main Window where will bind user control.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        Title="MyProject" WindowState="Maximized" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=uc:MainWindowViewModel}">
```

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
         <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CurrentViewModel is the property of MainViewModel.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
 private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;
        public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
        {
            get { return this._currentViewModel; }
            set
            {
                if(this._currentViewModel == value) { return; }
                this._currentViewModel = value;
                this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.CurrentViewModel);
            }
        }

    public MatterPanelViewModel MatterPanelViewModel { get; set; }
public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            this.MatterPanelViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetService<MatterPanelViewModel>();
        }
}



 public class MatterPanelViewModel:ViewModelBase
        {
            public MatterPanelViewModel()
            {

            }
        }
```

ViewModelBase here,

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
        {
            add { this._propertyChanged += value; }
            remove { this._propertyChanged -= value; }
        }

        private event PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged = delegate{ };

        protected void NotifyOfPropertyChange<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
        {
            var lambda = (LambdaExpression)property;
            MemberExpression memberExpression;
            if(lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
            {
                var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
                memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
            }
            else
            {
                memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
            }
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(memberExpression.Member.Name);
        }
        public void NotifyOfPropertyChange(string property)
        {
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(property, true);
        }
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property, bool verifyProperty)
        {
            var handler = this._propertyChanged;
            if(handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is only the DataTemplate, and it looks fine. You'll need to also provide us with your view model code along with the XAML control that's hosting it so we can see the binding.

Comment: edited. check please

Comment: are you getting any errors in the output window for this user control?

Comment: no error throwing

Comment: binding viewmodel namespace name only but usercontrol

Comment: When I set debugger into ViewModel Constructor and UserControl Constructor. ViewModel Constructor working but UserControl constructor

Comment: You don't seem to be actually setting the DataContext anywhere? You're setting `d:DataContext`, but that's only used in design mode.

Comment: but its set d:DesignInstance

Comment: Finally, I solve the problem. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solve the problem. The viewmodel and usercontrol map should under the MainWindow but here under main app. I just code from main app

```
<Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MatterPanelViewModel}">
            <uc:MatterPanel />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
```

to Main Window

```
<Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MatterPanelViewModel}">
            <usc:MatterPanel/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Then its working well.

Comment: Mark it as an answer if it solved your problem, so other people know.